# created custom year drop down field

Tags: django, django-forms

I've created year dropdown field. Here is [a code](http://dpaste.org/ahuBf/). It is showing in admin section. But when i tried to save the field. 
I get validation error `"Value u'2013' is not a valid choice"` Can someone help me? thanks

```
# fields.py

import datetime

from django.db import models

YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r, r))


class YearDropdownField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('editable', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 4)
        kwargs.setdefault('choices', YEAR_CHOICES)
        kwargs.setdefault('default', datetime.datetime.now().year)
        super(YearDropdownField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# models.py

year = YearDropdownField(_('Year'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
        YEAR_CHOICES.append((r, unicode(r)))
```